# How to make a while loop continue to loop if certain parameters aren't met?

Tags: python, while-loop

still a beginner at programming, so forgive the mistakes:

I am trying to make my user-defined function loop until the user types in "no."
However, when I was adding extra functions to foolproof the loop, i.e. check to make sure what they typed was actually "yes" or "no" and not random garbage/numbers, it seems to run into problems. Here is the loop statement:

```
while True:
    percentConvert()
    
    stop = input("Would you like to continue? yes or no: ".lower())
    print("You inputted:", stop) #added for debugging
    
    if stop != "no" or "yes":
        print("INVALID INPUT")
    
    elif stop == "no":
        break

    else:
        continue
```

First "if" is checking whether the input was not "no" or "yes", next "elif" is checking if the input was "no" and if so stop the program, and "else" (yes) continue. Instead, it asks if I would like to continue, tells me "INVALID INPUT" no matter what, and continues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't need the `else: continue`.

Comment: *if stop != "no" or "yes"* should be *if stop != "no" or stop != "yes"* Or, even better, *if not stop in {'no', 'yes'}*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stop != "no" or "yes"` is not the correct syntax. What you want is either `not (stop=="no" or stop=="yes")` or `stop not in ["no","yes"]`.

Consider the following modified version of your code:

```
while True:
    percentConvert()
    
    stop = input("Would you like to continue? yes or no: ".lower())
    print("You inputted:", stop) #added for debugging
    
    if stop not in ["no","yes"]:
        print("INVALID INPUT")
    
    elif stop == "no":
        break
```

Note that the above, while it technically runs, will run percentConvert() in response to an invalid input. Here's a script that behaves in what I suspect is the desired way.

```
while True:
    percentConvert()
    
    while True:
        stop = input("Would you like to continue? yes or no: ".lower())
        print("You inputted:", stop) 
    
        if stop not in ["no","yes"]:
            print("INVALID INPUT")
        else:
            break
    
    if stop == "no":
        break
```

In the loop as it's currently written, the condition is being interpreted as `(stop != "no") or ("yes")`. `"yes"` is a non-empty string, which Python considers to be a "truthy" value, which means that the `or` and `if` treat `"yes"` as if it were `True`, which means that the if-block always executes.

Comment: This will run, but I don't think it does what the OP wants it to do.  On bad input, this will print `INVALID INPUT` but will then go on and run `percentConvert()` just as though "yes" had been entered.

Comment: @CryptoFool Fair point; I'll change this accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for using custom error handling.

First define the base class for errors, and a custom exception.

```py
# define Python user-defined exceptions
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions"""
    pass

class InvalidInputError(Error):
    """Rasied when user input is not yes/no"""
    pass
```

Then in your while loop, you can use the exception.

```py
percentConvert()
while True:
    try:
        stop = input("Would you like to continue? yes or no: ".lower())
        if stop == 'yes':
            percentConvert()
            continue
        elif stop  == 'no':
            break
        else:
            raise InvalidInputError
    except InvalidInputError:
        print("Must enter either yes/no")
```